# How can I call a function from another function and how?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

This is my JavaScript written in HTML file itself where I want to call a `value(Time)` from a function written in code.gs file for getting time from spreadsheet. Also the function written below in JavaScript will run `onclick` of the button with the new URL having parameters of
time , the value called from spreadsheet code.gs

```html
<script >
    const getTimefromSheet = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(resolve).withFailureHandler(reject).getTimefromSheet());
    async function gettime(){
      const getTimefromSheett = await getTimefromSheet().catch(err => console.log(err));
      //  getTimefromSheett = google.script.run.getTimefromSheet();
     console(getTimefromSheett);
     return getTimefromSheett;
    }
     document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', _ => {
      var getT = gettime();
      addRow();
      console.log(getT);
      const css = document.getElementById("txt").value;
      document.getElementById('submit').href = <?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() ?> + `?v=form&input=${getT}`;

    }); 
  // google.script.url.getLocation(location);
```

The fuction which will return time is as follows:
code.gs

```js
function getTimefromSheet(){
  var sheetname = "Input";
  var rang = "C2";
  var tr = getDataFromSheet(sheetname,rang);
  
  var timestamp = tr.toString().replace(/\s/g, "");
  Logger.log(timestamp);
  return timestamp;
}
```

Kindly let me know that how can one pass the value from spreadsheet to the URL in parameters. I would need the unique URL for every user Hence this is the requirement for the same. I am new to this so how can I achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a simple modification, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, Javascript is modified.

```
const getTimefromSheet = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(resolve).withFailureHandler(reject).getTimefromSheet());

document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', async _ => {
  var getT = await getTimefromSheet().catch(err => console.log(err));
  addRow();
  console.log(getT);
  const css = document.getElementById("txt").value;
  document.getElementById('submit').href = <?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() ?> + `?v=form&input=${getT}`;
});
```

- When above script is run, `getT` is the value from `getTimefromSheet()`.
- In this modification, it supposes that `getTimefromSheet()` and `addRow()` works fine, and also, `<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() ?>` works fine. Please be careful this.

Comment: @kanu priya Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.